# Visible grid lines with CSS

Tags: html, css, grid

I'm working on a responsive website. The website has visible grid lines in the background, you can compare it to this one: http://fearonhay.com/ (very soft grey lines in the background). But there is one difference, which makes it a little harder for me to figure out the best way to solve it: The website is responsive (% widths).

I made a very rough draft, how it should look like. Actually there are not only three columns but four:

[image: Grid]

I created a quick fiddle (look at it in Chrome) to test, if it works the way I intented: http://jsfiddle.net/T76MK/

```
.lines {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(0, black 1px, transparent 1px);
    background-size: 25% 100%; 
}
.grid {
    margin-left: -30px; /* Gutter */    
}
.grid__item {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 30px; /* Gutter */
    vertical-align: top;    
}
.one-quarter { width: 25%; }
.red { background: red; }
```

As you can see I used a linear gradient for the lines, but the the second and fourth line are off by a few pixels. They aren't properly centered within the gutter. The third line looks fine though. Any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was/is a lot of issue with your code...

Here's what I'd do: 
http://jsfiddle.net/T76MK/7/

Question: why are you using double underscore here? Not good... `.grid__item`

Also, if you NEED those gutters (which you should never use negative margin for), likely you have some other code issues throughout the rest of your site/page you may want to look at.

Comment: Thanks, your code works only if all the columns have the same height, which isn't the case all the time. So i had to either fake the lines with a background gradient or i'll need to use an image for that and use background-size to stretch it to full height and width. I'm not sure, which one works better.
The "__" in my code are based on the BEM methodology (http://csswizardry.com/2013/01/mindbemding-getting-your-head-round-bem-syntax/ ), which works great for me. Bootstrap also uses negative margins for grids, why do you think i shouldn't use them to get rid of those :last-item classes?

Comment: I think you need to freshen up on your HTML and CSS, man. :) What you're suggesting above is not a good way to go about what you want to do - at all. I updated my answer with a clean solution. Let me know if that works for you...

Comment: Every method has its downsides. Your updated code probably works most of the time, but only if your ".grid_items" have the same width (in our case "one-quarter") and only fill one row. If you add more "grid_items" in your code, you won't see all of them, because of "height: 100%". Anyways thanks for your help!

Comment: Huh? Just add/change css classes? No different than your method, you'd need another image or to change the `background-gradient` hack too lol. If you're adding columns dynamically, use jQuery to assign set classes based on the number of columns. It'd be a few lines of code. Using an image for this and a background-gradient is very bad practice. You should really look at a CSS framework, like Zurb Foundation or Bootstrap. It'd solve a lot of your issues. The code I did follows the same structure. Avoid images and CSS3 hacks. No need, when you can do this with simple CSS with less code.

Comment: Thanks, i'll have a look into it.